# Is it possible to use Django with Qooxdoo framework?

Tags: django, qooxdoo

Guys i would like to use Django as my backend framework and qooxdoo as the frontend framework.

Is it practical to do this?

Has anyone tried to do this?

How did they do it?

Links and pointers would nice.

Gath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no direct experience using Django and qooxdoo, but the general answer to the question "Is it practical?" is: yes :). Although Django's default rendering behaviour is to produce HTML (which is unsuitable for a single page application like the ones you build with qooxdoo), it's easy to switch to returning e.g. Json on requests, which is a common format for the client-server communication between a qooxdoo frontend and a server. They just exchange data.

Has anyone tried to do this? - [Yes](http://n2.nabble.com/Table-pagination-and-best-practises-td3488141.html#a3488141), but they don't give much information on how, other than the before mentioned Json data exchange, implementing a Json RPC server in Django using [RPC4Django](http://n2.nabble.com/remote-request-is-always-GET-td3477991.html#a3477991).

AFAIK, there is no deeper Django integration, e.g. interfacing qooxdoo with Django views on the server (like [dojango](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/)).

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

- There is one elaborate product, [Sava](http://sava.oxys.net/), using qooxdoo for the frontend and Django for the backend. There is a short [overview](http://qooxdoo.org/community/real_life_examples#sava_repair_center_management), but I think it's closed-source so it only testifies to the "practicality" of using this technology stack. You probably won't learn in detail how it is realized.
- There is also [enre](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enre/), a qooxdoo-based GUI for Django. But I'm not familiar with it, and couldn't find any documentation on first glance, so I'm not sure what this really means.

Comment: someone has integrated [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) with django. Funnily enough called [dojango](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/)

Comment: @Sevenearths It's mentioned in the answer (towards the end).